# Sort a 3 level multi-dimension array by value in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

Here is the array,

```
array(
[0] => Array
        (
            [IdRedeemProduct] => Item-A
            [RedeemOptions] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [Points] => 1000
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [Points] => 2000
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [Points] => 43000
                        )

                )

            [ProductType] => 1
        )
[1] => Array
        (
            [IdRedeemProduct] => Item-B
            [RedeemOptions] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [Points] => 6200
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [Points] => 53000
                        )

                )

            [ProductType] => 1
        )
)
```

most of the usort examples are just 2 level dimension array. I couldn't find any example for 3 level.

In this case i wanted to sort the smallest points to show first. Item-A will be the first and Item-B will be the 2nd.

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach ($filteredResults as $key => $row)
                    {
                        foreach ($row['RedeemOptions'] as $key2 => $option) {
                            $vc_array_name[$key] = $option['Points'];
                        }
                    }

array_multisort($vc_array_name, SORT_ASC, $filteredResults);
```

this is working...

Comment: This works nicely. Thank you. You do not need the index in the second loop though.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  function sort_2d_desc($array, $key) {

    usort($array, function($a, $b) use ($key) {
        return strnatcasecmp($b[$key], $a[$key]);
    });

    return $array;
  }

       $a = [];
    foreach($arr as $key => $val){
        $a[$key] = $this->sort_2d_desc($val['RedeemOptions'], 'Points');
    }

    $newArr = [];
    foreach($arr as $key => $val){

        $newArr[] = ['IdRedeemProduct' => $val['IdRedeemProduct'], 'RedeemOptions' => $a, 'ProductType' => $val['ProductType']];
    }



    print_r($newArr);
```

Comment: return asort() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given. :(

Comment: Can you try it again?

Comment: this will only return the key instead of the value.. output: Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 1  )

Comment: This seems like its only for two levels though right? You should just add another foreach statement with $val as $key => $thirdVal

Comment: @bravonet try changing that `asort` to `sort`

Comment: @Buildersrejected I've just maintain his index and sort only what is inside the `RedeemOptions`

Comment: @aldrin27. it seem no difference. I will need to show the IdRedeemProduct in the output instead of just the  RedeemOptions array key.

Comment: @bravonet Kindly try again?

Comment: the result returning all the Points and is not sorting too :(

Comment: yes. is sorting by points but output will be the IdRedeemProduct value. anyway i found the solution. follow this method - https://www.virendrachandak.com/demos/how-to-sort-a-multi-dimension-array-by-value-in-php.php#multisort_2keys